# Crypto: Signing with Linux/gcrypt, Verifying with Android/Java

Tags: java, android, c++, cryptography

I am dealing with an existing system that gets a string in hex format, adds 8 trailing 0's, and signs it using gcrypt.  I am trying to make an Android version that can verify the signature.  The existing system works and cannot be changed.  I cannot, despite a lot of head scratching, make the android version work.

Both ends agree on the value of the data being signed, the bytes of the resulting signature, and the key being used.  I suspect the error is in the interpretation of the data being signed, which I honestly don't understand.

Let us say I am signing `"A5DA123456789B00000000"`
the linux end, in C++, does this:

```
#define FORMAT "(data\n (flags pkcs1)\n (hash sha1 #%s#))\n"
sprintf(blob, FORMAT, "A5DA123456789B00000000");
gcry_sexp_sscan(&keydata, NULL, blob, strlen(blob));
```

and then passes keydata as the second argument to `gcry_pk_sign`.

the android end, in Java, does this:

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sig.initVerify(pubkey);
BigInteger bigData = new BigInteger("A5DA123456789B00000000", 16);
sig.update(bigData.toByteArray());
boolean pass = sig.verify();
```

pass will be false.

I can sign things in Java, and Java says the signature is fine.
We have C code in linux which says the gcrypt signature is fine.
Is there some obscure setting involving pkcs1 that I've missed somewhere?  Or something obvious I'm missing?  Anyone know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the Java example, the "A5DA123456789B00000000" is being hashed with SHA-1. In the gcrypt example, that's the value of the hash. Try using sig.update("hello".getBytes("UTF-8")) in Java and "aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d" in gcrypt for example.

Comment: Oh gods, really?  Because it's actually an MD5 hash.  I thought it was getting hashed twice by some weird code, but it's actually treating it as a hash of a different type?  This could get really confusing.  It will be Monday before I can let you know if I got it working.  Thankyou for the direction!

Comment: What does `gcryp_sexp_sscan` do? A google search finds nothing. Please create a SSCCE. If you do I can at least give you one important hint.

Comment: Apologies - it is gcry_sexp_sscan, and it reads data from an s-expression.  Question edited to correct unforgivable spelling error.  The documentation is a little slim even when you spell it right though, and it seems kroot has more idea of what it will actually do than me (I assumed SHA1 meant "use SHA1", not "This is the result of SHA1").  Also, if I was able to make an SSCCE I wouldn't need to ask this question.  The above is an SSwrongCE and the best I can do at the moment :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my thanks to kroot for the significant clue about gcrypt behaviour.

For those that randomly find this question, the problem I had was the code was signing data in a manner which was ... odd ... and not supported by any of the Signature modes in Java.  The solution is to user a Cipher object instead.  The signature is nothing more than a private-key encrypted hash.  To verify it, use the corresponding public key to decrypt the signature and compare the result to the hash of the data being signed.